# Library Structure Convention

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, conventions

According to [Names of Assemblies and DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229048(v=vs.110).aspx), your library should be named by the following convention: `<Company>.<Component>.dll`. The problem is when you library incorporate projects like WPF Effects (special project that provide the effect build action) or WPF Custom Controls. Should you break the convention and have DLLs as follows:

```
MyCompany.MyLibrary.dll
MyCompany.MyLibrary.MyEffects.dll
MyCompany.MyLibrary.MyCustomControls.dll
```

Is there a way of combining all the different projects into a single DLL?

Comment: Besides that what you show wouldn't break any convention, you can of course have multiple namespaces in a single assembly (which is generated from a Visual Studio library project with multiple namespaces).

Comment: how about having only one dll. multiple projects equates to multiple dlls?

Comment: Each library project (if you talk about VS projects) generates an assembly DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you might be happy with putting all the code into one project and just namespace it accordingly.

In case it is your requirement to have separate assemblies you can merge it using Microsoft's [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) or with opensource [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack).